# Flutter ToggleButtons round each button's corners

Tags: flutter, dart, togglebutton, rounded-corners

I am basically trying to make a filter, the easiest tool I've found that fits my needs is Togglebuttons. The problem is that the default borderRadius only applies to the items in the corners (first and last) as rounding the corners of the widget as a whole, not every item.

I would like to know how to achieve [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5i9J.png) style,
and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTEQA.png) is what I currently have achieved.

My code is:

```dart
ToggleButtons(
  selectedColor: CustomColors.orangeDark,
  color: CustomColors.white,
  fillColor: CustomColors.white,
  textStyle: CustomTextStyles.menuOption,
  renderBorder: false,
  isSelected: isSelected,
  children: const [
    OpcaoFiltro("PROMOÇÕES"),
    OpcaoFiltro("LANCHES"),
    OpcaoFiltro("COMBOS"),
    OpcaoFiltro("BEBIDAS"),
  ],
```

with OpcaoFiltro() being:

```dart
class OpcaoFiltro extends StatelessWidget {
  const OpcaoFiltro(this.text, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      child: Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
        child: Text(
          text,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The ClipRRect makes it's child to have rounded corners, but the toggleButtons fillColor disregards that. Despite all my research I was not able to find an answer online. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this package => https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch?

It gives an option to have inner radius for individual toggle buttons.